# Find Minimum positive value in each row (exclude 0)

Tags: r, min

I am currently working with a matrix and I want to find the lowest positive value in each row.

Using apply(my.matrix,1,min) won't work since the output will always be 0...

Is there a way to find the lowest value excluding 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with an anonymous function.

```
apply(my.matrix, 1, FUN = function(x) {min(x[x > 0])})
```

Comment: Dear shujaa,

Thank you very much!
It worked perfectly! :)
Cheers,
J

Comment: Nice. Also ``min`` takes a ``na.rm = TRUE`` option, which may be useful. If negative values are also of interest, something like ``min(abs(x[x != 0]), na.rm = TRUE)`` on the rhs of ``FUN`` might do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

This variation on your approach works for me:

```
apply(my.matrix, 1, FUN=function(x) {min(x>0)})
```

Comment: `x > 0` is a boolean vector, just TRUE and FALSE, which gets coerced to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE when you look for it's minimum. This answer will return 0 if there are any numbers 0 or less, and return 1 otherwise.