# Extract index for minimum value per row (exclude 0)

Tags: r

I want to extract the index number of column where the `[4, ]` row has the lowest value. But 0 should not be included.
For example, in this given matrix `pos`,

```
> pos
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    1
[2,]    2    0    1    1
[3,]    9    0   10    8
[4,]   11    0   13   11
```

I want to have an output such as

```
1 4
```

Because they are 11 and the lowest values, or I can even just have either `1` or `4`.

Comment: I would say this is very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717831/find-minimum-positive-value-in-each-row-exclude-0). You just need to use `which.min` instead of `min` for the index.

Comment: doesn't `which.min` give only the first TRUE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Minimum positive value in each row (exclude 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717831/find-minimum-positive-value-in-each-row-exclude-0)

Comment: @doviod it does, but this is what OP posted as wanted output.

Comment: In her example she asked for the output to be `1 4`. The "either" option is a compromise. (also, I'm wondering which course is giving this exercise as homework... :) )

Comment: Thank you for the link! But it only prints the corresponding column of which last row has the minimum value. But I want to get the index of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
which(pos[4,]==min(pos[4,pos[4,]!=0]))
```

Not pretty, but gets it done. Tells you the column number where the value at row 4 equals the minimum value of row 4 excluding the zeros on that row.